# insert options with php and foreign key - not possible

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am building a simple web-database connection but when i assign a foreign key to my table than i am not able to insert data through html-php.
can anyone check my code and give me any suggestion/idea:

*person table Primary key is ID
foreign key : KEY `boardname` (`boardname`),
              KEY `depname` (`depname`)*

*board Table Primary key is boardname*

*deparment table Primary key is depname*

**Person table**

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `boardname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `bsdate` date NOT NULL,
  `budate` date NOT NULL,
  `depname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `desdate` date NOT NULL,
  `deudate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `boardname` (`boardname`),
  KEY `depname` (`depname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

**board Table**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
  `boardname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `boarddesc` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`boardname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Depament table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deparment` (
  `depname` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `depcomment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`depname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

now im using this simple script to insert data in the database and it not working i dont know why, but when i remove the foreign keys from person table it is working. any sugestion, i have to keep the foreign keys.

below is html php code:

**HTML FORM**

```
<body>
  <h1>New Student</h1>

  <form action="insert_student.php" method="post">
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="id" maxlength="30" size="13"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" size="13"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="surname" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Board Member From/Until</td>
         <!--<td><input type="text" name="boardid" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>-->
        <td><input type="date" name="bsdate" value="ICS" /><!--FSR-->
            <input type="date" name="budate" value="Infor" />
        </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>Department From/Until</td>
       <!-- <td> <input type="text" name="depname" maxlength="30" size="30"></td>-->
        <td><input type="date" name="desdate" value="ASE" />
            <input type="date" name="deudate" value="WEB" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

**PHP Insert**

```
<?php

  @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'e_kolori', 'kolori1515', 'e_color');

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  {
     echo 'Error: Could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
     exit;
  }

  $query = "INSERT INTO person (name, surname, bsdate, budate, desdate, deudate) VALUES 
  ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]', '$_POST[bsdate]', '$_POST[budate]', '$_POST[desdate]', '$_POST[deudate]')";

  $result = $db->query($query);
  if ($result)
      echo  $db->affected_rows.' student inserted into database.'; 

  $db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table specifies that all the fields are required.

Your insert statement is missing values for 'depname' and 'boardname'.

Also, (may not be relevant but worth checking) there must be the associated entries in your 'board' and 'department' tables *before* you insert a record that references them.

Answer (score 0):

Yepp Correct by removing the Not Null option in php myadmin I am able to insert data from the form but when i updated the form with those two fields **boardname** and **departmentname**  which are the foreign keys in my main table now i am not able to asign the boardname and depratmentname:
[by removing null working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjDtj.jpg)

and this is how my form looks like:
[Insert Form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXRB.jpg)

Should i make any change to my code somewhere i have no idea at the moment i have tried everything till now.

this is my new query in php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO person (name, surname, boardname, bsdate, budate, depname, desdate, deudate) VALUES 
  ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]', '$_POST[boardname], '$_POST[bsdate]', '$_POST[budate]', '$_POST[depname]', '$_POST[desdate]', '$_POST[deudate]')";
```